# How do I make a user a Guest User by default with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I want visitors to my site to have a default session of "Guest User" if they are not logged in.  I have created the Guest User in my users table, but how do I initiate a session for that user if the user is not signed in.

I could have a :set_user before filter in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :set_user

  private

    def set_user
      current_user || # Initiate a session with Guest here. But how?
    end

 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
sign_in(user)
```

I can't believe how long it took to figure that out!

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the current_user just create a new User instance. You could also save some unique identifier in it, that you also save in a cookie to recognize the user when he is coming back.

For example:

```
current_user ||= User.find_or_create_by_session_id( some_session_id_from_cookie )
```

Comment: There is a Devise helper called current_user. I need to call that helper from my views. I don't know what that helper uses to get the value of the user, but instantiating a User object alone won't do it.

Comment: Hm... I somehow assumed that, but thinking about it I can not really tell where that came from. I will do the thinking first next time.